# Weird gap between 'inline-block' for button or hyperlink tags

Tags: css

I'm kinda lost, because this is weird for me, it's supposed to not have gap between either `button` or `hyperlink` tags, because i use `display: inline-block`. I'm not using margin, and chrome inspector also telling me that there's no margins in-between.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7L2w.png

```css
.titlebar {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: var(--titlebar-color);
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-app-region: drag;
}

.titlebar * {
    -webkit-app-region: no-drag;
    height: 100%;
}

.titlebar a {
    all: unset;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: default;
    padding: 1px 11px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
    background: var(--titlebar-button-color);
}

.titlebar a#titlebar-title {
    background: var(--titlebar-button-title-color);
}
```

I also using `normalize.css` and `skeleton.css`.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/mahesha-c-gumelar/pen/jOBJgOK

How can I remove the gap between `hyperlink block`, any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Would you be able to share a portion of your code on https://codepen.io/pen/?

Comment: I've never seen any buttons showing up in the browser without HTML. Do you mind sharing your HTML with us? @FatihAktaş why codepen? there is "stacksnippets" inside the stackoverflow editor

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem**.

Comment: @caramba True, my bad!

Comment: @FatihAktaş Yes, here: https://codepen.io/mahesha-c-gumelar/pen/jOBJgOK

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Write item's html tags without enter or space, Like this:

```css
a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    background: gray;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <a href="#">1</a><a href="#">2</a><a href="#">3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is.. it's supposed to work with newline too.. but i guess i wrong. Anyway thank you!

Answer (score -2):

You can write font-size: 0 on the parent element, but set it back on the a tag
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xoQv.png)